# Code to float a div above canvas at point of click

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I've got an HTML5 canvas element and an event listener for clicks, what I need is to link this up to a floating div that appears right where the user clicks on the canvas. Code suggestions for best way to do this?

I'm tracking the mouse position with:

```
        var pos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
        mousePos.x = pos.x;
        mousePos.y = pos.y;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

**HTML:**

```
<div style="position: relative">
    <canvas />
    <div style="position: absolute" id="floatingDiv">Floating div</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var pos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
mousePos.x = pos.x;
mousePos.y = pos.y;
var floatingDiv = document.getElementById('floatingDiv');
floatingDiv.style.top = pos.y + 'px';
floatingDiv.style.left = pos.x + 'px';
```

Comment: Close but not quite working for me (in Firefox or chrome). The main canvas is centered on the page, the div ends up placed relative to the top left of the page, not relative to the canvas. Changing "position: absolute" to "position: relative" within the Floating div places it below the canvas.

Comment: Instead of centering the canvas, you should center the relative positioned element.

Comment: @ Sander: If you mean the containing div that's what I've done.

Comment: Try adding the left offset of the canvas to the pox.x, or create an example using www.jsfiddle.net